# Filtering data using a string array with operator and

Tags: excel, vba

I have the problem that i want to filter data with an string array (which is working fine), but the operator which is set is an 'OR' but i need an 'AND'.

The variable 'filter' is just a string array, declared like the following:

```
Dim filter() As String
```

and my actual excel data filter is this:

```
.Range("A1:AE" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filter, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

If i wouldn't use an array for the filtering, I would set the Operator like the following:

```
Operator:=xlAnd
```

Does someone know how I can set the Operator to 'AND' while using an string array?

Thank you!

Comment: How could that work? How would field 2 match all the values in your array at once?

Comment: @Rory I think their goal is to filter their range based on two or more different strings from their array

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thats is true, i need the amount of rows which are fitting on the strings out of that filter. I also tried already to change to Operator like this: 'Operator:= xlFilterValues And xlAnd' but it doesnt match to the amount of rows, which i get by doing the filtering manually

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem, actually. If you have values in your array the code you have above with just `xlFilterValues` *already* filters on every value in the array, acting as an "And" operator

Comment: I think you need to give us a few examples of data before filtering and then how the data should look after it filters the way you would like